# Java Intellij: Make change on external lib code and take effect immediately

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on Java with Intellij. Now I can debug into my external lib code by attaching source to jar lib. But now I want to make change on lib's source code and make it take effect immediately without repackaging to jar and including again to my main project. Can I do that ?

Comment: I think it's not possible, you will need to compile your changes back to jar file. Btw it's not a good practice to edit external Java library. You should override it then modify your own code.

Comment: I think jrebel (a commercial product) definitely allows that. I'm not certain, but I think IntelliJ [remote debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html) would probably also work.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good idea - conceptually.

Either something is an **external** library. Then its deployment artefact is a JAR. Or it is a "source project".

In other words: you are trying to eat the cake and have it at the same time. If it you find a technical way to hack yourself there - you shouldn't go there. Because it is conceptually wrong.

If the question is mainly about *dynamically* updating a running JVM - for that you can use tools such as JRebel. But that also requires that your JVM is running with the JRebel agent (which is fine for test/dev systems, but a no-go in production environments).

Comment: are there any tools like JRebel but free ?

Comment: @ThachHuynh The term to google for is "java code hotswap". See https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/4freewaystohot-swapcodeonthejvm for example. For the record: we are using JRebel, and yes, that costs money. But it is worth each cent (when your environment is such that you frequently have to swap code into test/dev systems).

Comment: What if I want to add loggers to the external library for debugging purposes?

Comment: @DiegoRamos In the end, it is all software, and you can do whatever you want (disclaimer: keep in mind that *legal* questions depending on your licences might arise). If you consider it worth to enhance a library like that, and to use that in your setup, sure, go for it. But you have to understand the associated *cost* of doing so. It costs you time and energy to get it to work, and then you have to ask yourself: should this be something *permanent*? If so, you either have to try to get it into the upstream code ... or **you** will be the one maintaining this code, and worse:

Comment: the one asked to **merge** things every time the external library changes. Just understand: this is a cost benefit thing: it is always about trade offs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code for the library, create a separate module with this source code and [add a dependency](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-projects.html#working-with-module-dependencies) on that module instead of a library jar.

And to have a jar library synchronized with the source code, you can configure the jar [artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#artifact_def) to be built from this library module together with the project build.

Answer (score 1):

For the other answers that are saying this isn't good practice, I agree but sometimes it can be useful. For example when I wanted to test a change in an external jar before submitting a merge request against the library with the suggested change. It was useful to be able to test it locally.

What I did was

1. Clone the library locally
2. Change the version in the pom.xml to something different e.g. `testing-snapshot`
3. Run `mvn clean install` in the new cloned project to load the project into your local m2 folder
4. In the your main pom.xml where you want your new version of the project to take affect, change the version to what you chose in step 2.
5. Now reload all maven project and intellij should pick up this new version which you can now edit the source code

Answer (score 0):

One trick to slightly modify a library's behavior (e.g., add logging statements for debugging purposes) is to override classes with your own implementation. With a bit of practice it takes just a few seconds and doesn't require repackaging:

1. Navigate to *source code* of the library class you want to modify and copy its *package name* to the clipboard (`CTRL+C`)
2. Navigate to class's *file* in project navigator (`Alt+F1`, `1`) and copy the *file* to clipboard (`CTRL+C`)
3. Navigate to your own source root in project navigator (`src/main/java`) and press `CTRL+V`
4. In the opening dialog, just fill out "Destination package" with the exact same package name as in the library (use `CTRL+SHIFT+V` for IntelliJ's clipboard history) and hit `OK`

You now have an *editable duplicate* of the class of interest (same class name and package name) and it will take precedence over the "original" from the library (because it comes first in the CLASSPATH).

Yes, this is a dirty hack. But also yes, it works reliably and should at least be fine for experiments/debugging.